# C++ | Как создать массив, кол-во значений которого будет содежаться в переменной?

Tags: c++

Как сделать так что-бы эта функция работала?

```
int *dae (int arr_count) {
int arr[arr_count];
for (int i = 0; i < arr_count; i++) {
arr[i] = i;
}
return arr;
}
```

Comment: Есть у меня подозрение, что вы не совсем корректно сформулировали вопрос... Скорее не "будет содержаться", а "становится известно во время работы программы". Да, в С++ стандарт не разрешает делать так, как делаете вы, и нужен либо динамически выделенный через `new` массив, либо просто вектор.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Она у вас и так работает. Кроме одного момента - вы создаете локальный массив в функции, и он уничтожается при выходе. Поэтому возвращение указателя на этот массив - ошибка, приводящая к неопределенному поведению.
Тут возможны варианты:

1. Создать массив до вызова функции и передать в неё указатель и размер

```
main()
{
    int arr[arr_count];
    dae( arr, arr_count);
}

int *dae (int* arr, int arr_count) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arr_count; i++)
        arr[i] = i;
    return arr;
}
```

2. Создать массив динамически через оператор `new[]`. Главное потом не забыть удалить его где-то с помощью `delete[]`. А чтобы не заморачиваться с удалением (временем жизни) массива, используйте умные указатели `std::unique_ptr()` или `std::shared_ptr()`.

```
int* dae (int arr_count) 
{
    int* arr = new int[arr_count];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr_count; i++)
        arr[i] = i;
    return arr;
}
```

3. Самый правильный способ, уже учитывающий правила управления временем жизни, умеющий не только копировать массивы но и перемещать - использование контейнеров стандартной библиотеки `std::vector<>` и `std::array<>`

```
vector<int> dae(int arr_count) 
{
    vector<int> arr(arr_count);    
    for (int i = 0; i < arr_count; i++)
        arr[i] = i;
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: *Она у вас и так работает. Кроме одного момента - вы создаете локальный массив в функции, и он уничтожается при выходе.* Я бы сказал, что основная проблема все же в том, что стандарт С++ VLA не допускает, так что вернуть ничего не получится просто потому, что и создать не удастся. Разве что в игнорирующем тесные рамки стандарта g++ :)